# What is the nature of an empty array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, size

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[0];
    printf("%d", array);
    return 0;
}
```

As we know, an array always points to its first item, but we don't have items in this example, but this code produces some memory address. What does it point to?

Comment: MSVC won't compile an empty array.

Comment: See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: You should mark the question as answered by @dbush

Comment: Did you read a recent C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) ?

Comment: @Tarik IIRC you have to wait 15 minutes after posting your question before accepting (though I might be remembering wrong). Great answer though!

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Ah, ok. I overlooked this constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array of size 0 is considered a constraint violation.  So having such an array and attempting to use it triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 6.7.6.2p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding constraints on Array Declarators states:

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type.  **If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.**  The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type.   The  optional  type  qualifiers  and  the  keyword `static` shall  appear  only  in  a declaration  of  a  function  parameter  with  an  array  type,  and  then  only  in  the  outermost array type derivation

GCC will allow a zero length array as an extension, but only if it is the last member of a `struct`.  This is an alternate method of specifying a *flexible array member* which is allowed in the C standard if the array size is omitted.

Comment: Off-topic probably but what does "or `*`" mean? I've never seen an array defined as `int foo[*];`

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 That's used in a function declaration where an array size is an earlier parameter and member names are not given, i.e. `void func(int x, int y, int arr[x][y])` can be declared as `void func(int, int, int [*][*])`

Comment: @dbush: `*` does not have to stand for an earlier parameter. It just indicates the array is a variable length array, in a function declaration. In the function definition, general expressions can be used there, including use of previous parameters, external identifiers, function calls, and so on.